# kubernetes hello world simple app does not work

Tags: kubernetes

i've followed a tutorial called hello-world on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaZpu4C4joM

i've changed only the name: "hello-world" to "admin"

here the code:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: admin-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: admin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: admin
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: admin
        image: dockercloud/hello-world
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "32Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
          - name: LISTEN_PORT
            value: "3000"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: admin-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: admin
  ports:
  - port: 4444
    targetPort: 3000
```

but it's not working when i call the server:

```
http://localhost:4444/
```

output doing:

```
kubectl describe service  admin-service


Name:              admin-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=admin
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.105.110.124
IPs:               10.105.110.124
Port:              <unset>  4444/TCP
TargetPort:        3000/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

what it's happening ?

thanks

UPDATE: i've add this ingress code to file:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello 
spec:
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: / 
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: admin-service 
                port:
                  number: 4444
```

but it's not working too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose your service to outside in some way:

1. Using a node port
2. Using an ingress controller
3. Port forwarding with kubectl

Easiest would be:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/admin-service 4444:4444
```

Comment: thanks, has you a link, or what is the easier way

Comment: thanks it's working, now can study deeply the anothers ways